# How long is marinated raw chicken breast good for after it's been vacuum sealed?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, vacuum

I have been marinating a large batch of chicken breast in eggs and spices. I'm going to put bread crumbs on them before cooking. I'm wondering, if I were to bread them and then seal them in vacuum sealer bags, how long would the uncooked meat be safe in the fridge after it has been vacuum sealed?

Comment: As a side note...I don't think it would be a good idea to bread them before vacuum sealing. Vacuum sealing prevents oxygen from getting to the meat. It doesn't prevent moisture from the chicken getting into the bread crumbs and making them soggy, and when it's time to fry them the bread crumbs will be very soggy and not give you a nice crunchy crust

Comment: See this answer too: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/52322/how-long-can-i-store-seasoned-vacuum-sealed-chicken/52335#52335

Answer (score 4):

I think vacuum sealed raw chicken breasts in the fridge [behave like not-vacuum-sealed chicken breast in the fridge](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9642/23376) because the meat is neither sterile nor less contaminated with bacteria than the non-vacuumed meat and there are surely bacteria that grow under anaerobic conditions. [The meat will be safe for 2 days](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/9644/23376).

Comment: What if it's forzen?

Comment: Well, you wrote "fridge", so I assumed that you stored your chicken breasts at 4°C ;) When it's frozen, theoretically you can store the food for ever. But: [the quality might be adversely affected](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/47149/23376)

Comment: Agreed ... home vaccum sealing is not like the commercial cryo-vac stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go much more than a week. When i worked in the restaurant biz that was generally the rule though we always sold out. If its going to be longer than that it needs to be frozen. If you see any darkening or discoloration its gotta go in the can. With chicken always better safe than sorry.